# Need explanations about the three % signs in print('Statistics = %.3f, p = %.3f' % (stat, p))

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining

I am learning data mining and have difficulty understanding below code.
Could anyone explain it to me? Thank you very much.

1. What are the uses of the three % signs? How to understand % (stat, p)?
2. How to understand the syntax stat, p = mannwhitneyu(data1, data2)?
   This is the first time I ask a question here. If I am not following the conventions or rules, please let me know. Thanks.

   from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu

   data1 = [23, 45, 78, 56, 48]
   data2 = [90, 43, 28, 79, 69]
   data3 = [87, 56, 29, 52, 39]

   ## compare samples

   stat, p = mannwhitneyu(data1, data2)
   print('Statistics = %.3f, p = %.3f' % (stat, p))

   ## interpret

   alpha = 0.05
   if p > alpha:
   print('Same distribution (fail to reject H0)')
   else:
   print('Different distribution (reject H0)')

Comment: This isn't related to statistics or data mining, it is one of Python's string formatting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3395177/2745495

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple arguments for string formatting in Python (e.g., '%s ... %s')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395138/using-multiple-arguments-for-string-formatting-in-python-e-g-s-s)

Comment: "*This is the first time I ask a question here. If I am not following the conventions or rules, please let me know.*" Welcome. Please have only 1 question per post, otherwise your question can be closed as "needs more focused". You currently have 2 here, 1 about string formatting and 1 about unpacking iterables. You should be asking separate, unrelated questions in separate posts.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me, Gino. I created another post for the second question.

Comment: Hi, Gino. I read the references you provided But I don't quite understand them. It's complicated for me as I don't know much about Python.  Could you please explain to me briefly the usage of the % signs in my question? Thank you very much.

Comment: *"It's complicated for me as I don't know much about Python."* That's why you should learn programming with Python properly before doing any course/subject with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Let simplify your question a bit.

```py
s = 0.12345
p = 0.6789
```

Now to print them with `%`

```
print('s = %.3f; q = %.3f' % (s, p))
```

This prints out

```
s = 0.123; q = 0.679
```

As you can see, `%.3f` limits the number of decimal places of **f**loat variables (which are `s` and `q`) to **3**.

I suggest you use [f-string](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/) in the future.